# RegEx String, 12 signs (at least 1 number and at least 1 letter)

Tags: regex

I have problems with RegEx. How do I get an 12 signs long part of a string which contains at least 1 number and 1 letter?

Example: *"This is 12 signs long: **F8ENL83I0E12** and maybe some more text"*

Comment: Does it contain only uppercase letters and numbers?

Comment: No, lowercase is possible too.

Comment: Looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050633/looking-for-a-regex-8-char-min-w-1-num-and-1-char) is what you're looking for.

Comment: @SoBiT: However, that will only work if the string contains nothing but that word. It will not work on your example string. Also, which language are you using for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find an alphanumeric word of length 12 within a longer text, use

```
(?i)              # Case-insensitive matching
\b                # Start of word
(?=[A-Z]*[0-9])   # Assert presence of at least one ASCII digit
(?=[0-9]*[A-Z])   # Assert presence of at least one ASCII letter
[A-Z0-9]{12}      # Match exactly 12 ASCII letters/digits
\b                # End of word
```

or (for JavaScript, because it doesn't support verbose regexes)

```
/\b(?=[A-Z]*[0-9])(?=[0-9]*[A-Z])[A-Z0-9]{12}\b/i
```